# ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import on Android

Tags: android, opencv, numpy, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to build an android app with buildozer (python-for-android). The app uses OpenCV for image processing and works like a charm on Ubuntu 14.01 LTS and Windows 7 and 8.1.

The building process with buildozer works fine and I can deploy the app on an Android device but the app crashes when I try to launch it on the device.

Here's the trace I get with adb logcat :

```
I/python  ( 9066): Initialize Python for Android
I/python  ( 9066): Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
I/python  ( 9066): Run user program, change dir and execute main.py
I/python  ( 9066): [WARNING           ] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 13)
I/python  ( 9066): [WARNING           ] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
I/python  ( 9066): [INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0
I/python  ( 9066): [INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, Sep 23 2015, 14:05:23) 
I/python  ( 9066): [GCC 4.8]
I/python  ( 9066): [INFO              ] [Factory     ] 173 symbols loaded
I/python  ( 9066): [INFO              ] [ImageLoaderFFPy] Using ffpyplayer 3.2-dev
I/python  ( 9066): [INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame, img_ffpyplayer (img_pil ignored)
I/python  ( 9066): [INFO              ] [VideoFFPy   ] Using ffpyplayer 3.2-dev
I/python  ( 9066): [INFO              ] [Video       ] Provider: ffpyplayer(['video_pygst', 'video_ffmpeg'] ignored)
I/python  ( 9066): [INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
I/python  ( 9066): [INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: pygame
I/libSDL  ( 9066): SDL_SetVideoMode(): application requested mode 1280x800
I/python  ( 9066): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 3.0 V@84.0 AU@  (CL@)>
I/python  ( 9066): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Qualcomm>
I/python  ( 9066): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Adreno (TM) 305>
I/python  ( 9066): [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
I/python  ( 9066): [INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>
I/python  ( 9066): [INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
I/python  ( 9066): [INFO              ] [Shader      ] program: <--From Vertex Shader:
I/python  ( 9066): --From Fragment Shader:
I/python  ( 9066): Link was successful.>
I/python  ( 9066): [INFO              ] [Support     ] Android install hooks
I/python  ( 9066): [INFO              ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
I/python  ( 9066):  ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
I/python  ( 9066):  Traceback (most recent call last):
I/python  ( 9066):    File "/home/florian/camtest/takepicture/android/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 27, in <module>
I/python  ( 9066):  ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
I/python  ( 9066): Python for android ended.
```

The python line where it crashes is when opencv is imported :

```
import cv2
```

The OpenCV version used is 2.4.11 (I also tried 2.4.9 and 2.4.10 by modifying the recipe.sh file in python-for-android's recipes folder)

The Numpy version used is 1.9.2 (I also tried 1.7.1 and 1.9.3 with no luck)

I honestly don't know what to do anymore, so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Does a plain `import numpy` work?

Comment: Apparently not. I tried importing numpy before cv2 and i got a new error :
I/python  (21438):  ImportError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "sqrt" referenced by "lapack_lite.so"...

Comment: Numpy has a few known problems with python-for-android - I got it working for me as described [here](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/pull/414) but I'm not sure those problems are related to this one. You could try the fix though to see if it works.

Comment: I tried it and it works ! Thanks a lot @inclement